# iOS/Swift/Firebase Authentication: Help Needed on Accessing "isNewUser"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

In my iOS/Swift/Firebase app, I am trying to access the "isNewUser" parameter after a user successfully signs in via email/password so that I can pop a window to compel them to reset their password from the temporary one initially assigned upon user creation.

Any insights would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a ISNewUser parameter? Can't find it in the Firebase documentation

Comment: There isn't. To detect if a user is new, compare the lastSignInDate  and creationDate properties in [the user's metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/UserMetadata).

Comment: I found the reference in the Firebase materials under "FirebaseAuth Framework Reference" for "AdditionalUserInfo" which, according to the materials "Indicates whether or not the current user was signed in for the first time."

Comment: A snippet of the code, which gives an "init() is unavailable" error, is:   Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailAddress!, password: accountPassword!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error == nil
                {
      if (AuthDataResult().additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser)!
   {
    self.forceNewPassword()
   }
     
      else
   {
    self.signinSuccess()
   }
                }
                else
                {
                    let errorCode = (error! as NSError).code
                    self.signinFailure(errorCode)
                }
            })

Answer (score 2):

The `.isNewUser` Bool is available from the FirebaseAuth AdditionalUserInfo class.
[Here is the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AdditionalUserInfo#/c:objc(cs)FIRAdditionalUserInfo(py)newUser). In order to utilize this code, please see a demo sign in function I wrote below.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)");
            return;
            
        }
        
        // Fetch the user's info
        guard let uid = result?.user.uid else {return}
        
        // Safely unwrap the boolean value rather than forcing it with "!" which could crash your app if a nil value is found
        guard let newUserStatus = result?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser else {return}

        // Test the value
        print("\nIs new user? \(newUserStatus)\n")
        
        if newUserStatus == true {
            // Provide your alert prompt

        }
        else{
            // Transition view to continue into the app

        }
    }
```

Comment: When would `additionalUserInfo` be nil though?