# Create a profile after user signs in Firebase and SwiftUI

Tags: user-interface, firebase-authentication, swiftui

The app should:

- create new profile with email or *Google Sign-In* or *Facebook Login*
- after creating the profile there is an email verification and then the user can sign in
- if is the first time it should show a page to create a new in-app profile (creating a document in the database with the uid of the user with description, skills...)
- but in this page if the user *Google Sign-In* it should show name and surname and the Google profile picture and let them add additional info such as description and their skills...

The first 2 steps are easy to achieve but how can I understand if the user just created the profile or he just logged out and in again or he simply uses *Google Sign-In* every time. And how can I take the user info from the database in Firebase and show it in the create in-app profile page.

Is it possible to achieve in SwiftUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect is a signed-in user is new, you can compare `lastSignInDate` and `creationDate` in the [`UserMetadata` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/UserMetadata).

Also see:

- [Get Created date and last login date from FIRUser with Firebase 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174178/get-created-date-and-last-login-date-from-firuser-with-firebase-3)
- [iOS/Swift/Firebase Authentication: Help Needed on Accessing "isNewUser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469092/ios-swift-firebase-authentication-help-needed-on-accessing-isnewuser), which shows the `isNewUser` that you can also sometimes use (depending on your implementation).